# Why doesn't oracle ignore referential integrity constraint for direct-path insert

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

According to,
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c21dlins.htm#10778

> During direct-path INSERT operations, Oracle appends the inserted data after existing data in the table. Data is written directly into datafiles, bypassing the buffer cache. Free space in the existing data is not reused, and referential integrity constraints are ignored. These procedures combined can enhance performance.

So the following SQL should cause the data to be inserted to table 'c'. But Oracle still checks for referential constraint, Why?

```
create table a(b varchar2(30));
alter table a add constraint "pk_a" primary key (b);
create table c(b varchar2(30), constraint "fk_b" foreign key(b) references a(b));

insert /*+ APPEND */ into c select 'a'||rownum from dual connect by level<=10000;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys. I should have searched this forum before asking this question,
Found the asktom link http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1211797200346279484 from the thread
[Direct-Path INSERT Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503932/direct-path-insert-oracle?rq=1)
which answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

As you shown nicely, referential constraints are **not** ignored during direct path insert. I'll try to find out why the 9i document says so....

Comment: Thanks for your time. The link to asktom(in my answer) answers why. Inadequate/misleading documentation from oracle I guess.

Comment: It's still in the 11.2 documentation. Tom's answer explaines well how it is, but for my taste it's a documentation bug...